# How to prove the continuity of [integral with variable bounds of non-continuous function] at essential (but not infinite) discontinuity point?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I'm currently studying the topic of the continuity of the integral $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$, where $a$ is an arbitrary constant.

I understand that if $f$ is a continuous function on the interval $[a, b]$, then $\displaystyle F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable on $(a, b)$.

I also learned that a sufficient condition for the existence of a definite integral of a function over an interval is that if $f(x)$ has only a finite number of discontinuities in the closed interval $[a, b]$ and is bounded, then $f(x)$ is integrable over $[a, b]$.

I've studied the cases where there is a removable discontinuity or a jump discontinuity in $f(x)$, and the continuity and differentiability of $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$ at these discontinuities. I understand that at a removable discontinuity, $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous and differentiable, and at a jump discontinuity, $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous but indifferentiable.

However, I'm curious about the case where $f(x)$ has an essential but not infinite discontinuity. Specifically, I'm wondering whether $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous and whether $\displaystyle \int_a^x f(t) dt$ is differentiable at points of essential but not infinite discontinuity. For example, consider the following function $f(x)$:

$$
f(x) = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle \sin \frac{1}{x}  & (x \neq 0) \\
\displaystyle 0 & (x = 0)
\end{array} \right. 
$$

I think the following $f(x)$ might be a better example, since I was able to find the function $F(x)$ whose derivative function is equal to $f(x)$, but I'm not sure if this function is representative of the general case.

$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
F(x) = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}  & (x \neq 0) \\
\displaystyle 0 & (x = 0)
\end{array} \right.
&,&
f(x) = F'(x) = 
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\displaystyle 2x \sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}  & (x \neq 0) \\
\displaystyle 0 & (x = 0)
\end{array} \right.
\end{array}
$$

Could you please help me understand this? Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Can you see (or show) that if $|f| \leq M$ and $I$ is an interval of length $h$, then $|\int_I f| \leq Mh$?

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang Thank you for your comment, but I'm sorry I don't know how to use that conclusion in this issue. For each inner point $c_k$ of the divided subinterval, there is $\min_{x \in [a,b]} f \cdot (b - a) = \sum_{k = 1}^n (\min_{x \in [a,b]} f) \cdot \Delta x_k \leq \sum_{k = 1}^n f(c_k) \cdot \Delta x_k = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ . The case for $\max f$ can be proved similarly. So I think the addition of the absolute value notation enables the conclusion that $|\int_a^b f(x) dx| \leq (\max_{x \in [a,b]} |f|) \cdot (b - a)$ .

Comment: The idea is, if $f$ is integrable on an interval containing $x$ and $x+h$, and if $|f| \leq M$, and if $F$ is a definite integral of $f$, then $$|F(x+h)-F(x)|=\biggl|\int_x^{x+h}f\biggr|\leq M|h|.$$That's enough to deduce (uniform, even Lipschitz) continuity of $F$ without triaging by the type of discontinuity of $f$. :) <> For differentiability, offhand I don't see a necessary criterion better than "look at the definition." But if $F'(x)$ does exist, it's easy to see the derivative may or may not be $f(x)$: We can redefine $f(x)$ without changing $F$. <> Do feel free to write your own answer!

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang I think I know how to prove continuity now:).\\ For any point $x_0$ of a bounded function $f$, to demonstrate that $F$ is continuous at $x_0$, is to show that $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} F(x) = F(x_0)$\\. That is, for any chosen $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that when $|x - x_0| < \delta$, the inequality $|F(x) - F(x_0)| < \varepsilon$ holds.\\ Based on the inequality, if take the integral bound to be $[x, x_0]$ ($x < x_0$), $\displaystyle |F(x) - F(x_0)| \leq (x_0 - x) \max_{x \in D_f} |f|$ holds.  (1/2)

Comment: Then, for any chosen $\varepsilon$, let $(x_0 - x_a) \max_{x \in D_f} |f|$ be $\varepsilon$. For all $x \in (x_a, x)$, $\displaystyle |F(x) - F(x_0)| \leq (x_0 - x) \max_{x\in D_f} |f(x)| < (x_0 - x_a) \max_{x\in D_f} |f(x)| = \varepsilon$.\\ So that the lower bound neighbourhood of $x_0$ is found, which is $x_a$. By the same method, the upper bound $x_b$ of the neighbourhood on the other side of $x_0$ can be found. The values $x_a$ and $x_b$ provide the $\delta$ required to ensure the continuity of $F$ at $x_0$.\\ Thanks again for your assistance! (2/2)